# Cant build simple QT5 project

Tags: qt, cmake, g++, qt5, qt-creator

I setup QT for windows using this tutorial - https://wiki.qt.io/MinGW-64-bit

I need to use CMAKE

I create empty project in qtcreator, but when i try cmake it i get this errors:

```
Starting to parse CMake project, using: "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug", "-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:STRING=C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe", "-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_TARGET :STRING=x86_64-pc-msys", "-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:STRING=C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe", "-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER_TARGET:STRING=x86_64-pc-msys", "-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:STRING=C:/msys64/mingw64", "-DCMAKE_SYSROOT:STRING=C:/msys64", "-DQT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE:STRING=C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/qmake.exe".
The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.2.0
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/msys64/mingw64/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:53 (message):
  The C++ compiler

    "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Temp/QtCreator-RwlXKb/qtc-cmake-tQFVtoZK/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):C:/msys64/usr/bin/ninja.exe cmTC_373cd && [1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_373cd.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj
    FAILED: CMakeFiles/cmTC_373cd.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj 
    C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe --sysroot=C:/msys64     -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_373cd.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj -c testCXXCompiler.cxx
    /bin/sh: C:msys64mingw64bing++.exe: command not found
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Temp/QtCreator-RwlXKb/qtc-cmake-tQFVtoZK/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Temp/QtCreator-RwlXKb/qtc-cmake-tQFVtoZK/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
CMake Deprecation Warning:
  The 'cmake-server(7)' is deprecated.  Please port clients to use the
  'cmake-file-api(7)' instead.


CMake Project parsing failed.
```

It seems error in this string:

```
 C:msys64mingw64bing++.exe
```

It because slashes not handled correctly.

So how i fix it? Where there setings stored?

**UPDATE 1**

Here is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(t2 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Quick REQUIRED)

if(ANDROID)
    add_library(t2 SHARED main.cpp qml.qrc)
else()
    add_executable(t2 main.cpp qml.qrc)
endif()

target_compile_definitions(t2
  PRIVATE $<$<OR:$<CONFIG:Debug>,$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>>:QT_QML_DEBUG>)
target_link_libraries(t2
  PRIVATE Qt5::Core Qt5::Quick)

# QtCreator supports the following variables for Android, which are identical to qmake Android variables.
# Check http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/deployment-android.html for more information.
# These variables must use CACHE, otherwise QtCreator won't see them.

#if(ANDROID)
#    set(ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android" CACHE INTERNAL "")
#    if (ANDROID_ABI STREQUAL "armeabi-v7a")
#        set(ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/libcrypto.so ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/libssl.so CACHE INTERNAL "")
#    endif()
#endif()
```

I try and launch `cmake CMakeLists.txt` and it crete makefile

```
# CMAKE generated file: DO NOT EDIT!
# Generated by "Unix Makefiles" Generator, CMake Version 3.15

# Default target executed when no arguments are given to make.
default_target: all

.PHONY : default_target

# Allow only one "make -f Makefile2" at a time, but pass parallelism.
.NOTPARALLEL:


#=============================================================================
# Special targets provided by cmake.

# Disable implicit rules so canonical targets will work.
.SUFFIXES:


# Remove some rules from gmake that .SUFFIXES does not remove.
SUFFIXES =

.SUFFIXES: .hpux_make_needs_suffix_list


# Suppress display of executed commands.
$(VERBOSE).SILENT:


# A target that is always out of date.
cmake_force:

.PHONY : cmake_force

#=============================================================================
# Set environment variables for the build.

# The shell in which to execute make rules.
SHELL = /bin/sh

# The CMake executable.
CMAKE_COMMAND = /usr/bin/cmake.exe

# The command to remove a file.
RM = /usr/bin/cmake.exe -E remove -f

# Escaping for special characters.
EQUALS = =

# The top-level source directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR = /c/projects/t2

# The top-level build directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_BINARY_DIR = /c/projects/t2

#=============================================================================
# Targets provided globally by CMake.

# Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
rebuild_cache:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Running CMake to regenerate build system..."
    /usr/bin/cmake.exe -S$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR)
.PHONY : rebuild_cache

# Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
rebuild_cache/fast: rebuild_cache

.PHONY : rebuild_cache/fast

# Special rule for the target edit_cache
edit_cache:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Running CMake cache editor..."
    /usr/bin/ccmake.exe -S$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR)
.PHONY : edit_cache

# Special rule for the target edit_cache
edit_cache/fast: edit_cache

.PHONY : edit_cache/fast

# The main all target
all: cmake_check_build_system
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start /c/projects/t2/CMakeFiles /c/projects/t2/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start /c/projects/t2/CMakeFiles 0
.PHONY : all

# The main clean target
clean:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 clean
.PHONY : clean

# The main clean target
clean/fast: clean

.PHONY : clean/fast

# Prepare targets for installation.
preinstall: all
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 preinstall
.PHONY : preinstall

# Prepare targets for installation.
preinstall/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 preinstall
.PHONY : preinstall/fast

# clear depends
depend:
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -S$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 1
.PHONY : depend

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named t2

# Build rule for target.
t2: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 t2
.PHONY : t2

# fast build rule for target.
t2/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/t2.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/t2.dir/build
.PHONY : t2/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named t2_autogen

# Build rule for target.
t2_autogen: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 t2_autogen
.PHONY : t2_autogen

# fast build rule for target.
t2_autogen/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/t2_autogen.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/t2_autogen.dir/build
.PHONY : t2_autogen/fast

main.o: main.cpp.o

.PHONY : main.o

# target to build an object file
main.cpp.o:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/t2.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/t2.dir/main.cpp.o
.PHONY : main.cpp.o

main.i: main.cpp.i

.PHONY : main.i

# target to preprocess a source file
main.cpp.i:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/t2.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/t2.dir/main.cpp.i
.PHONY : main.cpp.i

main.s: main.cpp.s

.PHONY : main.s

# target to generate assembly for a file
main.cpp.s:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/t2.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/t2.dir/main.cpp.s
.PHONY : main.cpp.s

t2_autogen/EWIEGA46WW/qrc_qml.o: t2_autogen/EWIEGA46WW/qrc_qml.cpp.o

.PHONY : t2_autogen/EWIEGA46WW/qrc_qml.o

# target to build an object file
t2_autogen/EWIEGA46WW/qrc_qml.cpp.o:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/t2.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/t2.dir/t2_autogen/EWIEGA46WW/qrc_qml.cpp.o
.PHONY : t2_autogen/EWIEGA46WW/qrc_qml.cpp.o

t2_autogen/EWIEGA46WW/qrc_qml.i: t2_autogen/EWIEGA46WW/qrc_qml.cpp.i

.PHONY : t2_autogen/EWIEGA46WW/qrc_qml.i

# target to preprocess a source file
t2_autogen/EWIEGA46WW/qrc_qml.cpp.i:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/t2.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/t2.dir/t2_autogen/EWIEGA46WW/qrc_qml.cpp.i
.PHONY : t2_autogen/EWIEGA46WW/qrc_qml.cpp.i

t2_autogen/EWIEGA46WW/qrc_qml.s: t2_autogen/EWIEGA46WW/qrc_qml.cpp.s

.PHONY : t2_autogen/EWIEGA46WW/qrc_qml.s

# target to generate assembly for a file
t2_autogen/EWIEGA46WW/qrc_qml.cpp.s:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/t2.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/t2.dir/t2_autogen/EWIEGA46WW/qrc_qml.cpp.s
.PHONY : t2_autogen/EWIEGA46WW/qrc_qml.cpp.s

t2_autogen/mocs_compilation.o: t2_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.o

.PHONY : t2_autogen/mocs_compilation.o

# target to build an object file
t2_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.o:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/t2.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/t2.dir/t2_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.o
.PHONY : t2_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.o

t2_autogen/mocs_compilation.i: t2_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.i

.PHONY : t2_autogen/mocs_compilation.i

# target to preprocess a source file
t2_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.i:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/t2.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/t2.dir/t2_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.i
.PHONY : t2_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.i

t2_autogen/mocs_compilation.s: t2_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.s

.PHONY : t2_autogen/mocs_compilation.s

# target to generate assembly for a file
t2_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.s:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/t2.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/t2.dir/t2_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.s
.PHONY : t2_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.s

# Help Target
help:
    @echo "The following are some of the valid targets for this Makefile:"
    @echo "... all (the default if no target is provided)"
    @echo "... clean"
    @echo "... depend"
    @echo "... rebuild_cache"
    @echo "... t2"
    @echo "... edit_cache"
    @echo "... t2_autogen"
    @echo "... main.o"
    @echo "... main.i"
    @echo "... main.s"
    @echo "... t2_autogen/EWIEGA46WW/qrc_qml.o"
    @echo "... t2_autogen/EWIEGA46WW/qrc_qml.i"
    @echo "... t2_autogen/EWIEGA46WW/qrc_qml.s"
    @echo "... t2_autogen/mocs_compilation.o"
    @echo "... t2_autogen/mocs_compilation.i"
    @echo "... t2_autogen/mocs_compilation.s"
.PHONY : help



#=============================================================================
# Special targets to cleanup operation of make.

# Special rule to run CMake to check the build system integrity.
# No rule that depends on this can have commands that come from listfiles
# because they might be regenerated.
cmake_check_build_system:
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -S$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
.PHONY : cmake_check_build_system
```

when i try to build it with `make`i get

```
C:\projects\t2>make
[ 16%] Automatic MOC and UIC for target t2
[ 16%] Built target t2_autogen
[ 33%] Automatic RCC for qml.qrc
Scanning dependencies of target t2
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/t2.dir/t2_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.o
[ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/t2.dir/main.cpp.o
[ 83%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/t2.dir/t2_autogen/EWIEGA46WW/qrc_qml.cpp.o                                                                                                                                   
[100%] Linking CXX executable t2.exe
CMakeFiles/t2.dir/main.cpp.o:main.cpp:
(.text$_ZN15QTypedArrayDataItE10deallocateEP10QArrayData[_ZN15QTypedArrayDataItE10deallocateEP10QArrayData]+0x1c): undefined reference to `QArrayData::deallocate(QArrayData*, unsigned long, unsigned long)'
CMakeFiles/t2.dir/main.cpp.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN15QTypedArrayDataItE10deallocateEP10QArrayData[_ZN15QTypedArrayDataItE10deallocateEP10QArrayData]+0x1c): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `QArrayData::deallocate(QArrayData*, unsigned long, unsigned long)'            
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status    
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/t2.dir/build.make:126: t2.exe] Error 1   
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:77: CMakeFiles/t2.dir/all] Error 2   
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

Here source code of program:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Please provide the *exact* build commands you use to run CMake. It would appear your problem stems from there.

Comment: You might try changing the `:STRING` to `:PATH` for the `cmake` command line arguments that are actually paths. Or, leave these `:STRING` demarcations out altogether.

Comment: squareskittles: where i can find this settings?

Comment: It seems you have gotten past the original error? Now, you have a linker error.

Comment: Nope i do it from command line, but before i use Qtcreator to try to configure it

Comment: I added more info abut project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i fix it, it seems that Ninja tool cause all problems under windows!

I remove all files from my simple project, so it contains only this files:

```
CMakeLists.txt                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Makefile                                                                                                                                                                                                           
main.cpp                                                                                                                                                                                                           
main.qml                                                                                                                                                                                                           
qml.qrc
```

In Qtcreator i go to Tools - > Options -> Kits

CMake generator -> MSYS Makefile

In Cmake tool select with path `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\cmake.exe` or you maybe need to add it manually

After i press Ok and exit from options all works just fine. CMAKE configure project and compile it and it runs.

Comment: And also it now compile from command line too, after `make clean`